# How to submit certificate request from Red Hat machine to Windows CA?

Tags: redhat, certificate, ad-certificate-services, windows-server-2022

I’m looking for solution, which helps me send certificate request from domain-joined RedHat Enterprise Linux machine to Certification Authority on Windows Sever 2022. Is there any solution to do this? I know that I can generate request manually and send it via e-mail or smth but I don’t want to. At this moment, I can generate .csr using OpenSSL and send it via Certificate Web Enrollment page. And it works. But it is a such manually process.

I searched many Google pages and I didn’t find any complementary solution. I want request SMIME type user certificate, for encrypt and signing files/e-mails. I have an administrator account on both systems. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This forum is typically for solutions that you already have. The automation of tasks such as this are common, but requesting solutions for same are off-topic in this forum.

Comment: Sure… I wanted to comment on similar topic but I don’t have enough reputation points. So I decided to write a new question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to submit certificate request from RedHat machine to Windows CA?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1134414/how-to-submit-certificate-request-from-redhat-machine-to-windows-ca)

Comment: You need a solution to create a text file based on criteria, transfer the file to a CA, have a certificate issued and transfer a certificate file back, and execute the fulfillment on the endpoint. Or use builtin APIs provided by the certificate issuer. That could be multiple things. Certificate distribution and management of the certificate lifecycle  could be a half-baked Python "script", and workflow in an existing Config Management solution, or an elaborate system that manages hundreds of thousands of certificates with multiple data flows, workflows, and assembly line.