# How to submit certificate request from RedHat machine to Windows CA?

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, windows

I’m looking for solution, which helps me send certificate request from domain-joined RedHat Enterprise Linux machine to Certification Authority on Windows Sever 2022. Is there any solution to do this? I know that I can generate request manually and send it via e-mail or smth but I don’t want to. At this moment, I can generate .csr using OpenSSL and send it via Certificate Web Enrollment page. And it works. But it is a such manually process.

I searched many Google pages and I didn’t find any complementary solution. I want request SMIME type user certificate, for encrypt and signing files/e-mails. I have an administrator account on both systems. Can anyone help me?